# GGraph and formatting nodes

Tags: r, filter, ggraph

I would like to format the non leafs different, but I am unable to find more information on aes for the filter. What are the different possible values?

Here is an example

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

gr <- graph_from_data_frame(flare$edges, vertices = flare$vertices)
ggraph(gr, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter=leaf, size=3, color="white") , alpha=0.5)
```

What do I have to put in the filter for taking the root or other nodes?

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of search I found it.

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

gr <- graph_from_data_frame(flare$edges, vertices = flare$vertices)
ggraph(gr, 'dendrogram') +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_point(aes(filter=leaf==TRUE, size=3, color="white") , alpha=0.5)+
  geom_node_point(aes(filter=leaf==FALSE, size=3, color="red") , alpha=0.5)
```

It is also possible to filter an property, hat is available in the vertices.

Comment: Where did you find this information?  I trying to do something similar with the text, however now my "origin" is printing - which I do not want.

Comment: It's a long time ago I have done this. Unfortunately I cannot remember where I found these information.